# FlexSlider Active Image in MainSlide not in SubSlide

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

I have a problem with my carousel. And I'm using Flexslider plugins. If I tried to select different slides and the subslide pop-out, the active slide that I clicked in the main slide is not showing instead the 1st slide only. And, same as subslide when I close it.

**I want to:**

1. When SLIDE BOX is displayed, the image clicked in MAIN-SLIDE is displayed in SUB-SLIDE.
2. When the SLIDE BOX is closed, the image clicked in SUB-SLIDE is displayed in MAIN-SLIDE.

Please click the codepen for the sample.

**Code:**
https://codepen.io/venJ7/pen/yLYGvJG

```
$(function() {
        $('#slider').flexslider({
            directionNav: false,
            controlNav: true,
            animationLoop: false,
            slideshow: false,
        });
        $("#photo_box").hide();
        $("#slider ul li > a").on("click",function(){
                $("#photo_box").slideToggle(200);
                $('body').css({'overflow':'hidden','height':'100vh'});
                $('#carousel').flexslider({
                    animation: "slide",
                    directionNav: false,
                    controlNav: false,
                    animationLoop: false,
                    slideshow: false,
                    itemWidth: 100,
                    itemMargin: 5,
                    asNavFor: '#slider2'
                });
                $('#slider2').flexslider({
                    directionNav: false,
                    controlNav: false,
                    animationLoop: false,
                    slideshow: false,   
                    sync: "#carousel",
                    start: function(slider){
                      $('body').removeClass('loading');
                    }
                });
        });
        $(".photo_close").on("click",function(){
                $("#photo_box").hide();
                $('body').css({'overflow':'auto','height':'auto'});
        });
        $("#slider img").on("click", function(e){
            var image_src = $(this).attr('src');
            $('#carousel img').each(function(key,val){
                var sub_img = $(this).attr("src");
                if (sub_img == image_src) {
                    $(this).parent("li").addClass("flex-active-slide");
                    $(this).find("flex-active-slide").click();
                }else{
                    $(this).parent("li").removeClass("flex-active-slide");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```